# How to split a domain name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to create one function in jquery, which separate domain name.

i.e. If Domain name = "google.co.in" or "google.com" it should separate domain and store two variable in jquery as domain name = "google" and TLD = "co.in".
I try little bit on this and here is my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a66L5/)**, Here Is my code

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str = "www.google.co.in";
var res = str.split(".",1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Leave the `split` as just `str.split(".")`, this will return you array with each part, eg: `["www", "google", "co", "in"]` and you can derive what you need from that instead.

Comment: What about when there is no subdomain specified?  Is the url coming from user entry, because if it is then you need some robust validation before you start splitting and assuming the position of the domain name.

Comment: @Archer yes entries are from user input

Answer (score 2):

Try llike this:

```
var res = str.split(".")[1];
var rest = str.split(".")[2] + "." + str.split(".")[3];
```

Comment: But what, if domain .com ? its display."comundefine"

Comment: ask if (str.split(".").length == 3){}

Answer (score 2):

`var ls = self.location.hostname.split( "." );`

will give you

`["www", "google", "at"]`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/a66L5/2/

I altered your javascript code to use the $.each function from jQuery. As when you do `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;` it will only display the first element of your array:

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = "www.google.co.in";
        var res = str.split(".");
        var html = "";
        $.each(res, function(key, value) { html += value + "<br />" });
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>
```